# How to a convert a 2D vector into an angle

Tags: vector, trigonometry

How do you calculate the angle between the line from the origin to a point $(x,y)$ and the horizontal axis?

Answer (score 7):

Use

```
ArcTan[x, y]
```

Reference: [`ArcTan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArcTan.html).